# Normalized graph cut

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, spectral-graph-theory, clustering

Is finding the normalized cut of an undirected weighted graph the same as normalizing the weights and finding the cut?

Consider finding the minimum cut (min-cut) of a connected, undirected weighted graph $G(V, E)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E = \{w_{i,j}\} \text{ where } i,j \in V$ is the set of weighted edges.
A min-cut is found by minimizing the cost function:

$$C(A,B) = \sum_{a \in A, b \in B} w_{a,b} \\
\text{where } A \cup B = V, \ A \cap B = \emptyset $$

A min-cut can produce small clusters in the case of sparse graphs, as the cut would consider only the local information of edges, which does not reflect how the weights are distributed in the other parts of the graphs. In order to overcome this, the idea of a normalized min-cut was proposed by [Shi et al](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/868688).
A normalized min-cut is found by minimizing the cost function:
$$N_{cut}(A,B) = C(A,B) * (\frac{1}{deg(A)} + \frac{1}{deg(A)}) \\
\text{where } deg(A) = \sum_{a\in A}w(a,v), \forall v \in V
$$

Could we normalize all the edge weights between $[-k, +k]$ where $k \in R^+$ and we minimize the min-cut cost function to find the normalized min-cut. The results turn out to be the same as the normalized min-cut when tested on several samples empirically.
Also, the complexity of finding the normalized min-cut is $O(2^n)$ and there are no known efficient algorithms to find the exact solution.
Although there are efficient algorithms for finding the min-cut when edge weights are non-negative, there are no known efficient algorithms to find the exact solution of the min-cut when the edge weights are both positive and negative (complexity is again $O(2^n)$, proven [here](http://www.iasi.cnr.it/ResearchReports/R00524.pdf)).

Please help in proving that finding the normalized min-cut of an undirected weighted graph is the same as normalizing the weights and finding the min-cut.
If not, provide at least a counterexample when these two methods will not produce the same solution.